# Forming second order differential equation from given solutions using the Wronskian. (and some general help)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For 
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space 
(\star)$$
 we have
 $$W'(x)=-p(x)W(x) \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (\dagger)$$
 where $W(x)$ is the Wronskian defined as 
$W(x)=y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2$ 
for linearly indepedent solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ of $(\star)$.

The question asks us to use this to find $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ such that
 $y_1(x)=1+\cos x$ and $y_2=\sin x$. Solving $(\dagger)$ for $W(x)$ we
 have $W(x)=W_0\int^x_{x_0}-p(u) \space du$.

> Here's where I'm having issues; my notes have that $W_0=W(x_0)$ for
>   some $x_0$, now it says we can pick $x_0$ as whatever we like and I'm
>   fine with that, but what was bothering me (and the question goes onto
>   ask) is that if we can pick $x_0$ as whatever we like, what happens at
>   $x_0=\pi$? We would get $W=0$ which is confusing me as Abel's theorem
>   has that $W(x)=0$ or $W(x)\ne0$ for all $x$-
>
> Have I misunderstood?
>
> Further, if we can have $W_0$ as whatever we like by picking 
>   convenient $x_0$, we can surely just pick $W_0=1$ then putting in the 
>   given $y_1$ and $y_2$ we have $(1+\cos x)\sin x+\sin x\cos x=\sin 
>  2x+\sin x=\exp({\int^x_{x_0}-p(u)\space du})$ $$\implies p(x)=-\frac 
>  d{dx}(\log(\sin 2x+\sin x)=-\frac{2\cos 2x+\cos x}{\sin 2x+\sin x}$$
>   where does $q(x)$ come into things? Setting $q(x)=0$ with this $p(x)$
>   does not work.

I think I just haven't quite got my head around some of this stuff yet so an answer or general help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you solved (cross) correctly. (I don't know the LaTeX symbol for that.) You would have to divide both sides by W(x) then integrate both sides. You'd have $ln|W(t)|-ln|W(t_0)|$ on the left, and on the right you'd have the minus integral of $p(t)$. You could then do some algebra to solve for $W(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot choose $x_0=\pi$, since you will see that at that point $p(x)$ is not continuous. And this is a necessary condition for Abel's Theorem.

To find $p(x)$, compute $W=y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2=\cos x+1$. Then plug this into
$$W'(t)=-p(x)W(t).$$
Since $W'(t)=-\sin x$, this gives you
$$p(x)=\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}.$$
Then use the original equation. Plug any one of $y_1$ or $y_2$ into it. You can then get $q(x)$.

Comment: Excellent thank you very much